# How can I report on Salesforce's 'External Email limit' for my specific organization?

Tags: governorlimits, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I was looking at the Governor Limits page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

And I wanted to see if we can see how close our org comes to these 2 specific limits. Can we report on these? What are our options?

- Email Services – (Maximum Number of Email Messages Processed)
- External Email limit – 5,000 per 24 hrs (GMT timezone)

I'd like to know where we stand before we look into kicking off more emails via the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a REST API for this, `/services/data/vXX.X/limits` (where `XX.X` is a specific API version, such as 42.0), which returns a JSON file like the following:

```
{ ...
  "DailyWorkflowEmails": {
    "Max": 123,
    "Remaining": 12
  },
  ...
  "MassEmail": {
    "Max": 123,
    "Remaining": 12
  },
  ...
}
```

You can read more about this resource in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm).